# making my aspx (developed with html5 codes) as my master page for my web application

Tags: javascript, css, html, visual-studio, master-pages

I have done a aspx file filled with my GUI, image button and image slide shows. I developed all these 3 functions by using HTML5, CSS and javascript. However, the html5 was completed in the aspx file format in visual studio 2012. I attempted to create a new master page in order to make my GUI standardized for all my other web form. I then copied the codes of my aspx file(filled with html5 codes) into the master page and this is the error I got.

PS : I'm doing a web application using visual studio 2012 with html5, css and javascript

Link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/snSlk.jpg

HTML5 CODES ( in aspx file format )

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GUI.master.cs" Inherits="MP.GUI" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Police Website</title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!-->
var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "image/s1.jpg"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "image/s2.jpg"
var image3 = new Image()
image3.src = "image/s3.jpg"
var image4 = new Image()
image4.src = "image/s4.jpg"
var image5 = new Image()
image5.src = "image/s5.jpg"
//-->
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />

<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <script src ="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1    (beta2)/IE8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->    

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>

    <ul id="Slideshow">
<img src="image/s1.jpg" name="slide" width="1215px" height="250px">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var step = 1
function slideit() {
    document.images.slide.src = eval("image" + step + ".src")
    if (step < 5)
        step++
    else
        step = 1
    setTimeout("slideit()", 2500)
}
slideit()
//-->
</script>
</ul>

<%-- <input type="image" id="header" style="height:250px;width:1148px;" src="image/header.jpg" /> --%>
<input type="image" id="myimage" style="height:53px;width:200px;" src="image/logo.jpg" />

<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Recent cases</a></li>   
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>      
</ul>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>    
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the start up page of the website/web application. this error is not related to Master page Concept. Use above master page on that page. It should work.

Comment: what i mean is that i want to set the GUI i coded in my aspx (filled with html5) as a master page so i can standardized all the GUI of my web forms. However i tried to convert the extension which obviously wont work. And i tried another method by copying the code into the master page which evetually lead me to the error as stated above.

Comment: Do it step by step:
1.Add a new master page using visual studio wizard.
2.Copy only the HTML not the whole page as it involves @Page Directives.
3.Then use that Master Page for another aspx page.
4.Set that page as startup. It won't cause any error.

Comment: hmm i did that before. right-click my file, add new item, select master page. I will have some blank gui with some back-end source code. hence the codes that i have pasted in my master page is stated above.

Comment: if site is deployed on IIS : set default document.
if asp.net wed dev then set startup project and set start page